# Method setAlpha() does not get called in onTouchListener ACTION_MOVE event

Tags: android, transparency, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I am trying to change the alpha of an `ImageView` by moving the finger on the screen. I have an `OnTouchListener` and in `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` I have put the below code. `Log` shows the alpha value changing fine when moving the finger, but `setAlpha` method does not change the alpha of the view. The image appears just once with random alpha transparency and stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button2){          
        longClicked = true;                 
    }
}

private OnTouchListener dialpadTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            if (longClicked) {
                mainView.addView(msg, msgParams);
                mainView.addView(remove, removeParams);
                longClicked = false;
            }
            int alpha = (int)(viewY - event.getRawY());
            msg.setAlpha(alpha);
            Log.i(TAG,"Alpha set to " + alpha);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you getting alpha value in log ?
alpha value range between 0-255 
0=transparent 
255- opaque

Comment: I get values from -100 to 200 and above, depending on where my finger is.